# How to see if a particular git hash has a git tag associated with it?

Tags: git

I am trying to figure out how to see if a particular hash has a git tag associated with it through the git commands.

I know that

```
git show-ref -s my_tag
```

returns the HASH of the tag. but what about the other way around?

I am unsure of what to try. I've read through the git documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+tags+point+commit

Comment: `git tag --points-at <SHA1>`